# PHP auto delete file after timer

Tags: php

I've been working with this code all day but for some reason files won't get deleted after timer has run out.$zip_file_name is the file that I'd like to see gone after 30secs

```
    $the_folder = '../test';
$zip_file_name = ("PHOENIX_fullbackup_$now.zip");


$download_file= true;
//$delete_file_after_download= true; doesnt work!!


class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {
    /** Add a Dir with Files and Subdirs to the archive;;;;; @param string $location Real Location;;;;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;; @author Nicolas Heimann;;;; @access private  **/

    public function addDir($location, $name) {
        $this->addEmptyDir($name);

        $this->addDirDo($location, $name);
     } // EO addDir;

    /**  Add Files & Dirs to archive;;;; @param string $location Real Location;  @param string $name Name in Archive;;;;;; @author Nicolas Heimann
     * @access private   **/
    private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
        $name .= '/';
        $location .= '/';

        // Read all Files in Dir
        $dir = opendir ($location);
        while ($file = readdir($dir))
        {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') continue;
            // Rekursiv, If dir: FlxZipArchive::addDir(), else ::File();
            $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
            $this->$do($location . $file, $name . $file);
        }
    } // EO addDirDo();
}

$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if($res === TRUE) 
{
    $za->addDir($the_folder, basename($the_folder));
    $za->close();
}
else  { echo 'Could not create a zip archive';}

if ($download_file)
{
    ob_get_clean();
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private", false);
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($zip_file_name) . ";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_name));
    readfile($zip_file_name);


  if ($handle = opendir ($zip_file_name)) {

    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (filectime($file)< (time()-30)) {  // timer -30secs
          unlink($file);
        }
    }
  }

}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.thanks

Comment: Seems adequate since the site is on LAN.thanks

Comment: After the download has completed the script stops and never reaches the 30 seconds. You have to set up a cron job which checks regularly if there are files older than 30 seconds and delete them.

Comment: is there a need to delete the file after 30 sec? couldn't you run the `unlink` code after `readfile` to delete the file after serving to the user? alternatively, why not leave the file in there after download and add check to your script at the begining `if (file_exits(..)) { unlink(..) }`? i.e. old generated zip file are deleted before new one is generated and served.

Comment: @Reeno Thanks for  your reply.Can I setup a cron job on the same php ?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Yeah it doesn't have to be 30 secs as long as its deleted thats fine thanks.I've tried unlink but no go

Comment: Cron jobs are set up outside of the PHP script. A cron job runs a PHP script. Just google a bit how they work :)

Comment: @LatheesanKanes Can you Kindly provide me with a code where it would unlink existing file.As you've probably guessed my php skills are terrible.thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you could delete zip file (if it already exists) prior to generating the zip file - so that old files are deleted first before new ones are generated:

E.g. (snippet of your code)

```
<?php

// Delete previous zip files
$old_files = glob($the_folder .'/*.zip');
foreach ($old_files as $old_file) {
    unlink($old_file);
}

// Usage
$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($zip_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) 
{
    // Add Files to Zip
    $za->addDir($the_folder, basename($the_folder));
    $za->close();

    // Download If enabled
    if ($download_file)
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private", false);
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($zip_file_name) . ";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zip_file_name));
        readfile($zip_file_name);
    }
}
else
{
    echo 'Could not create a zip archive';
}

?>
```

Comment: Thats it thanks Latheesan Kanes ..thats awesome works perfectly.Can i use a wildcard on the $zip_file_name because $now = date("Ymd").so if user comes back 2 days after the $zip_file_name won't be the same.thanks again

Comment: i've updated my answer. the script now will go into what ever dir specified in `$the_folder` and find all files with extension `.zip` and deletes them.

Comment: I'm more than happy to do it but i won't be able to accept it because my rep should be not less than 15 ,unfortunately i'm at 14 so right once i pass that point i'll be sure to accept your answer thanks again.

Comment: awesome. After having posted my answer, just had a thought; if one or more user is tring to download the zip file at same time, you'll run into some trouble. You could improve that code a bit more by only deleting zip file older than say 1 hour.